# Concatenating cell array of one size matrices into one multidimentional matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, concatenation, cell-array

Assuming I have a cell array of matrices of one size:
{m1,m2,m3,m4...}.
Is it possible to concatenate them along the 3rd dimension without using cycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cat(3,m{:})`. The `m{:}` creates a comma separated list which unpacks your cell to individual arguments.